# Deploy to EC2 instance from Github Actions

Tags: amazon-ec2, deployment, github-actions

Good night guys, I've been trying to find out this but it's the first time I'm doing it.

With Github OpenID connect I could to deploy the code to a S3 bucket, but now I need to pass these files from s3 to an EC2 instance in the `deploy.yml` file, but I can't use

```
access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

Because the client doesn't want to give access to secrets.

There's any other way to do this?

I'm completely lost and I don't have administrator access or the enough permissions in AWS to work.

Thanks.

I have already the files in a S3 bucket with this code:

```
    - name: Copy to S3 bucket
      run: |
        aws s3 sync --delete ./my_path s3://${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }}/${{ steps.extract_branch.outputs.branch }}/${{steps.extract_hash.outputs.commit_hash }}
```

And I've been trying to do something like this:

```
    - name: Deploy to EC2 instance
      uses: easingthemes/ssh-deploy@v2.1.5
      env:
        SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: "ALL PRIVATE KEY CODE PASTED"
        SOURCE: "./"
        REMOTE_HOST: "my host"
        REMOTE_USER: "my user"
        TARGET: "/path/to/copy/"
        EXCLUDE: "/dist/, /node_modules/, /venv/"
```

This is the error:

```
Run easingthemes/ssh-deploy@v2.1.5
[general] GITHUB_WORKSPACE:  /home/runner/work/project
[SSH] Creating /home/runner/.ssh dir in  /home/runner/work/project
✅ [SSH] dir created.
[SSH] Creating /home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts file in  /home/runner/work/project
✅ [SSH] file created.
✅ Ssh key added to `.ssh` dir  /home/runner/.ssh/deploy_key
[Rsync] Starting Rsync Action: /home/runner/work/project/docker/ to ubuntu@ec2-server.com:/home/ubuntu/
⚠️ [Rsync] error:  rsync exited with code 255
⚠️ [Rsync] stderr:  Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-server.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Load key "/home/runner/.ssh/deploy_key": error in libcrypto
ubuntu@ec2-server.com: Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(228) [sender=3.2.3]

⚠️ [Rsync] stdout:  
⚠️ [Rsync] cmd:  rsync /home/runner/work/project/docker/ ubuntu@ec2-server.com:/home/ubuntu/ --rsh "ssh -p 22 -i /home/runner/.ssh/deploy_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" --recursive -rltgoDzvO
 1: 0xa1a640 node::Abort() [/home/runner/runners/2.299.1/externals/node12/bin/node]
 2: 0xa90649  [/home/runner/runners/2.299.1/externals/node12/bin/node]
 3: 0xc06599  [/home/runner/runners/2.299.1/externals/node12/bin/node]
 4: 0xc08387 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/home/runner/runners/2.299.1/externals/node12/bin/node]
 5: 0x140dd19  [/home/runner/runners/2.299.1/externals/node12/bin/node]
```